# Solspace Freeform plugin: Multi page form not going to next page

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace

I have a multi-page form set up. No matter what I enter on page 1, the form doesn't submit - the page just reloads.
Looking in devtools - the POST data is there, but seems like Freeform is not recognising it to move to page 2.

Any help appreciated!